# Get column index using column name mySql

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, location, primary-key

I need a query that will give me the name and location (index of the column) of `PRIMARY KEY` 
in different tables.

I can find the name of the `PRIMARY KEY` column using:

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`WHERE 
    (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'dbName') AND (`TABLE_NAME` = 'tableName') 
    AND (`COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI');
```

How do I get it's column position by that name or by another method?

Comment: Have you looked at all the fields in that table???  A 5 second google showed me that there is an `ordinal_position` field...

Comment: Thanks, very new to mysql :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT ORDINAL_POSITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='your_db_name' AND TABLE_NAME ='your_table_name' 
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'your_column_name'
```